# Connect Meteor app to remote DB running on AWS Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2

So, here is the situation: I have AWS EC2 instance where my Meteor application is running with local MongoDB (deployed with mupx). I want to use my remote MongoDB that is running on AWS Linux instance instead. I tried to specify remote mongo_url in mup.json file as follow:

```
"MONGO_URL": "mongodb://INSTANCE_IP:27017/name_of_application"
```

And then redeploy the application with following commands:

```
mup stop -> mup reconfig -> mup start **or** mup stop -> mup setup -> mup deploy.
```

Neither way worked and application still uses local db rather than remote one.
Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

**UPD:** 27017 port is enabled in both instances. However I just created a new empty instance (port 27017 is enabled as well) and tried to deploy my application there with same settings except I do not create local MongoDB environment. It gave me an error when I run

```
mup deploy
```

Error as follow:

```
Verifying deployment
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] x Verifying deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
rscore.js:750:1)
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:102:1)
    at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (accounts_common.js:23:18)
    at new AccountsServer (accounts_server.js:16:5)
    at Package (globals_server.js:5:12)
    at /bundle/bundle/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1814:4
    - - - - -
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:556:74)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)

=> Redeploying previous version of the app

-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Have no idea what is going on here. Hope you know the answer. Thanks!

**UPD_2:** I've added user name to this line in mup.json:

```
"MONGO_URL": "mongodb://user_name@INSTANCE_IP:27017/name_of_application"
```

And disabled MongoDB in mup.json. Also I updated security rules on both instances so inbound/outbound connections are open on 27017 port and after all this changes on mup deploy I got new error:

```
x Verifying deployment: FAILED

-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
 to the latest stable version, run:
npm WARN deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest
npm WARN deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you
npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if
npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)
npm WARN deprecated 
npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with
npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS
npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small
npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
=> Starting meteor app on port:80

=> Redeploying previous version of the app

-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: check firewall rules, Also, are you on private or public IP range? (should be private)

Comment: my only concern about firewall rules is that there is no pre-specified connection type for MongoDB(as there is one for My SQL for example) so I choose "Custom TCP" - could it be the issue too? I would check IP range, thank you for advice!

Comment: Had a look at IP range - they are private and DB instance points to Application only, and Application points to DB only.